# Check if suggestions widget is opened in Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I have a Monaco editor, and want to override the "Enter" key, but if suggestions widget is opened then it should act the normal thing (select the active item in the suggestions)
I need to have something like

`editor.isSuggestionsWidgetOpened()` 
or better
`editor.isTextFocused()`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and needed to know if the suggestion widget was open.

This is my solution

```js
let isSuggestionOpen = false;

const suggestionWidget = editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.suggestController')?.widget;

if (suggestionWidget) {
  suggestionWidget.value.onDidShow(() => {
    isSuggestionOpen = true;
  });
  suggestionWidget.value.onDidHide(() => {
    isSuggestionOpen = false;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what i need using this function:

```js
 (editor as any).addAction({
      id: 'my-close',
      label: 'Close',
      keybindings: [monaco.KeyCode.Enter],
      // && !parameterHintsVisible
      precondition: '!suggestWidgetVisible && !markersNavigationVisible && !findWidgetVisible',
      run: async () => {
        const { lineNumber } = editor.getPosition();
        const lineCode = extend.getCodeInRange(lineNumber, lineNumber);
        if (!lineCode || !lineCode.trim()) return;
        const code = extend.getCodeInRange(1, lineNumber);
        this.drawEditorRunIcon('loadingDecoration', editor.getPosition(), `Executing "${lineCode}"`);
        await this.runModel(code);
        this.removeEditorRunIcon('loadingDecoration', editor.getPosition());
        extend.selectNextLine(true);
      }
    });
```